# Camel Case the project name for a Visual Studio Project Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to make a Visual Studio Project Template.  I can easily replace the names of things I want to have the same name as the project using `$safeprojectname$`

So if my project was named `WidgetHunter` and I named a file `$safeprojectname$.js` it would be called `WidgetHunter.js` when the project was created.

But what if I wanted to name the file `widgetHunter.js` or `widget-hunter.js`?

**Is there away to make a new variable that does not have a static value?**  (I need to perform a string operation on the supplied project name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this will not be as straight forward as you allude.  Project Templating is not very powerful, it's basic replacement, you can't really run code AFAIK.

However, you can "easily" add a Wizard Step (`IWizard`) that adds additional keys to the replacement dictionary.  For example, you could add `$safeprojectnameforjs$` which has the manipulated value.

```
 public class ExampleWizard : IWizard
 {
     public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
    {
         replacementsDictionary.Add("safeprojectnameforjs",
            YourCustomMethodForManipulatingName(replacementsDictionary["safeprojectname"])
    }

    // there are a few other IWizard methods you'll need to 
    // implement but don't need to do anything in
 }
```

To wire in your ExampleWizard, you'll need to add a tag in your .vstemplate

```
<VSTemplate>
  <WizardExtension>
     <Assembly>ExampleWizard.ExampleWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     
        PublicKeyToken=a76e3e75702e3ee4</Assembly>
      <FullClassName>ExampleWizard.ExampleWizard</FullClassName>
   </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

**Note:** You'll need to have your Wizard in an assembly.  Easiest way is to create a new Class Library project.  Also, it **will** need to be signed (at least, pretty sure that's still a requirement).

Finally, you'll need to update your VSIX manifest, so that you have the Wizard assembly wired up as an assembly dependency:

```
<PackageManifest>
   <Assets>
      <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="ExampleWizard.ExampleWizard" Path="|ExampleWizard.ExampleWizard|" AssemblyName="|ExampleWizard.ExampleWizard;AssemblyName|" />    
   </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work for you.  I'm not an expert, but I had to solve a similar problem a few months back, and I pulled this together from the code I wrote back then.

Comment: If you're looking for proper walk throughs, look for "VS Project Template Wizards"